# Item on ground won't go away

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have this item on the ground I keep trying to remove I tried burning it and dropping it into the void but it just respawns I can't seem to get rid of it any help would be nice! Btw I'm on my Bukkit 1.11 server if you need to know

[image: The Item]

Comment: Have you restarted your server since this has started to occur?

Comment: Look up. It is probably bugged on a roof, but shown down there. Therefore actions on floor do nothing to it, because it is on the roof.

Answer (score 1):

Look up.

The item is probably above and has glitched through the block it is on top of. I can see some fence posts looking like they're holding something up, check up on top of this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this has plagued me before but one of these should fix it

1. Try digging around the dirt to see it it falls this might be a glitched entity.
2. Try installing clearlagg and removing the entities in the world.
3. Try rebooting your server.